# Translate the HEADER of RailsCast calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
HEADER = %w[Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday].map{ |key| I18n.t(key, scope: "table") }
```

but the `I18n.locale` is `null` so it gives me the default translation.

Even if I set  `I18n.locale = "ru"` in the `module CalendarHelper`  like that:

```
module CalendarHelper
  def calendar(date = Date.today, &block)
    Calendar.new(self, date, block).table
  end
  I18n.locale = "ru"
  class Calendar < Struct.new(:view, :date, :callback)
HEADER = %w[Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday].map{     |key| I18n.t(key, scope: "table") }
START_DAY = :sunday
.......
```

the `I18n.locale` is `null` and I get the default translation.

But if I set `I18n.locale = "ru"` within the class it works fine.

```
 class Calendar < Struct.new(:view, :date, :callback)
I18n.locale = "ru"
HEADER = %w[Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday].map{ |key| I18n.t(key, scope: "table") }
START_DAY = :sunday
.......
.........
```

how can I pass the  `params[:local]` from the view to `class Calendar` or is there another solution to translate the `HEADER`?

Comment: RailsCast calendar code : Railscasts PRO #213 Calendars (revised).

I trying  to translate the HEADER :

Comment: the locale is only valid during a request-response, and not while you set up a model. Think of it: the locale depends on the user requesting your website. When you define the model, there is no user yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I translated the headers.  First, comment out the HEADER declaration...

```
  class Calendar < Struct.new(:view, :date, :callback)
    #comment out or remove the line below
    #HEADER = %w[Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday]
    START_DAY = :sunday
```

Then where the header is defined, replace the HEADER.map with I18n.t(:"date.day_names").map  This pulls the day names directly from the config/locales/ *.yml files.

```
    def header
      content_tag :tr do
        I18n.t(:"date.day_names").map { |day| content_tag :th, day }.join.html_safe
      end
    end
```

Now just declare the locale from the params in your controller and you should be all set.